# android app unsupported for all devices on google play?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, google-play, google-play-services

I published an Android app on the google play store but it says that it is incompatible with ALL devices:

**Unsupported devices:15023**

Below is the listings from Google play developer console

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

menifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="masco.mis.software.mascoapproval">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<application
android:name=".Tapplication"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_masco"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyC7UKI8yiVrzUllwLS3V2_b-H5Mor54KGc"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/ic_message"/>
<meta-data  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
android:resource="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<activity android:name=".MapActivity">
android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity" >
<meta-data
android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
android:value=".HomeActivity"/>
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".LoginActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".HomeActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".chatoperation.NewChatOperationActivity">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".IntroActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".chat.ChatOperationActivity"/>
<receiver
android:name=".TReceiver"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
android:name=".service.LocationTService"
android:exported="false"/>
<service
android:name=".service.CountTService"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true"/>
<service
android:name=".service.FCMService"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
</intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name=".fcm.FcmToken">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
</intent-filter>
</service>
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

my gradle dependency looks below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
applicationId "masco.mis.software.mascoapproval"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 25
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
{exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.0'
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.1'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.11'
compile 'com.github.markomilos:paginate:0.5.1'
compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But this app runs without any problem  when I test it with physical device and also on emulator(api 19,22,25) on android studio.

Comment: Have you set min and max in your manifest?

Comment: Yes. I have just added my menifest, please have a look

Comment: <activity android:name=".MapActivity">
android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity" > looks broken, typo?

Comment: how come I didn't notice that before and android studio didn't raise any complain. you have sharp eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indicated the camera feature in your manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera" android:required="true" />
```

but it **must** be all lowercase:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

No device has `android.hardware.Camera` which is why you are compatible with zero devices.

Comment: worked like a charm...
now 
Supported devices:
10957
Unsupported devices:
4073

Comment: by the way, I can't believe who answered my question.
I used to watch your lessons almost everyday on youtube. :)

Comment: Yay! Glad you got it working and I definitely appreciate the kind words :)

Comment: I'm rather new to android development and this is my first app. 
Can you give me a clue, why still Unsupported devices: 4073 ?

Comment: I suspect if you look up some of the devices on your unsupported list, most will be tablets that either don't have a camera (more common) or perhaps don't support being locked in portrait (less common).